# spectrum of an induced algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive group defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $B$ be a fixed Borel subgroup of $G$. Suppose $X=Spec(R)$ is an affine scheme with $B$ rationally acting on it; hence $B$ acts on $R$. Then one can construct an induced $G$-algebra as follow:
$$ S=(k[G]\otimes R)^B. $$
Now, is it true that the spectrum of $S$ is the associated scheme $G\times^BX$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X=pt$, then $G\times^B X=G/B$ is the flag variety, which is not affine.

However we have $S=\Gamma(G\times^B X, \mathcal O)$ and hence $spec(S)$ is the affinization of $G\times^B X$.

Comment: Ah, you got there first...

Comment: I had to type slightly less :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan! Is it possible to determine $spec(S)$? In some cases, it looks like $G\cdot X$ but I'm not sure if it's true in general.

Comment: What do you mean by $G \cdot X$?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear in my last question. I just didn't understand what "affinization" means. I was considering the example when $X=\mathfrak{u}$, the Lie algebra of the unipotent radical subgroup of $B$, and $B$ acts on it as conjugation, denoted by a dot "$\cdot$". Then we have $G\cdot\mathfrak{u}$ is the nilpotent cone of Lie$(G)$ which is the spectrum of $(k[G]\otimes k[\mathfrak{u}])^B$.

Comment: The affinization of a scheme $X$ is $spec(\Gamma(X,\mathcal O)$. In the situation of the question this means $G\times^B X=spec(S)$ if and only if $G\times^B X$ is affine. For example if $X=u$ then $G\times^B u$ is the nilpotent cone, which is affine hence the desired equality holds.